# Matching a string with regex and returning part of it

Tags: c++, regex, boost

my first question :)

I have a regex pattern to find the line I'm looking for in log, but I want to get part of this line.

Pattern:

`.*127\.0\.0\.1\]\s.*REGISTER\srequest\ssip:.*\.com.*`

Line:

> 2014-07-31 15:42:09,110 810310621 [RMI TCP Connection(18)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG - Incoming REGISTER request sip:example.com

I use boost::regex to find the line and it works perfect however, I would like to get the domain name or at least its position in line. What function should I look for?

Comment: captured with `()` [Undestanding captures](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/captures.html)

Comment: Provide grouping (`()`) in your regex pattern for the parts you want to extract after matching.

Comment: Use a capturing group and the [`regex_search`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/) method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using sregex_iterator:

```
#include <boost\regex.hpp>
int main()
{
    using namespace boost;

    std::string example("2014 - 07 - 31 15:42 : 09, 110 810310621[RMI TCP Connection(18) - 127.0.0.1] DEBUG - Incoming REGISTER request sip : example.com");

    regex xpr("127\\.0\\.0\\.1\\].+REGISTER\\srequest\\ssip\\s:\\s(.+\\.com)");    
    for (sregex_iterator it(example.begin(), example.end(), xpr), end; it != end; ++it)
    {
        smatch m = *it;
        std::cout << "Found: \"" << m[1] << '\"' << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Note that using std::regex /sregex_iterator is the same.